# Remove GMT-0400 part from the time but display (EDT)

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am getting time in this format:

[image]

How do I display timezone without GMT-0400 in the string?
So in the image above: I want to display
 **Wed Aug 30 2017 18:36:49 (EDT)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add a filter after your value such as:

{{value | "EEE MMMM d y HH:mm:ss (Z)" }}

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: (Z) returns -0400 and not EDT